# moving 2 objects at same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitouch

In my current ios project, I have dedicated one side of the screen to one object and the other side of the screen to the other object and i have made it so that if you swipe your finger across one side of the screen on the designated object would move. However, I want to make it so that you can move both objects at the same time in different movement but i cannot figure out how to do so. Below is my current code.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    if (location.x <= 270 ) {
        [Person setCenter:CGPointMake(location.x, Person.center.y)];

    }
    else  {
        [Person1 setCenter:CGPointMake(location.x, Person1.center.y)];
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    if (location.x <= 270 ) {
        [Person setCenter:CGPointMake(location.x, Person.center.y)];
    }
    else  {
        [Person1 setCenter:CGPointMake(location.x, Person1.center.y)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should start handling multiple touches that are delivered in the `touches` set - loop through all the `UITouch` objects and do your handling.

Edit:
here's your code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for(UITouch *touch in [event allTouches]) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

        if (location.x <= 270 ) {
            [Person setCenter:CGPointMake(location.x, Person.center.y)];
        }
        else  {
            [Person1 setCenter:CGPointMake(location.x, Person1.center.y)];
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for(UITouch *touch in [event allTouches]) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

        if (location.x <= 270 ) {
            [Person setCenter:CGPointMake(location.x, Person.center.y)];
        }
        else  {
            [Person1 setCenter:CGPointMake(location.x, Person1.center.y)];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I face the same problem with this code as i did with my original code. I have attempted to rework my approach to coding my mechanic but I can't quite figure out how to get the objects moving simultaneously thank you for your input however

Comment: @user3795419 so what's happening when you start making multiple touches? could you describe? the code should work... thanks

Comment: I can only move one of the objects at once. When I attempt to move both objects simultaneously by swiping my fingers across the designated areas, only one of them moves

Comment: @user3795419 I found out that instead of looping through `touches` set, you should rather go through `[event allTouches]` set. I've edited my code. now it should work. GL

Comment: @user3795419 any news? is it working now? please mark the post as answer if this answers your question. thanks.

Comment: yes its working but a bit fidgety. they sort of move simultaneously but one of then lags a lot in the movement

Answer (score 0):

If you move the -touchesBegan & touchesMoved code into the Person view class rather than the view/or viewController class it is in currently then those views can handle touches independent of each other and simultaneously.

*Edit: More info:
Currently you are handling touches events (in I'm guessing a UIViewController) using the code you pasted above, if you moved that code into your Person class you have created you could make the code simpler and achieve the result you desire. 
This will have the effect that the Person will decide if it is being touched and where and will move itself accordingly.

In your Person.m file add this code,

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.superview];
    [self moveToLocation:location];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.superview];
    [self moveToLocation:location];
}

-(void)moveToLocation:(CGPoint)location{
    CGFloat halfOfPersonWidth = self.bounds.size.width /2.0f;
    CGFloat halfOfSuperviewWidth = self.superview.bounds.size.width/2.0f;

    // Stop Person from going off left screen edge
    if ((location.x - halfOfPersonWidth) <= 0.0f){
        return;
    } // Stop Person from going off right screen edge
    else if ((location.x + halfOfPersonWidth) >= self.superview.bounds.size.width){
        return;
    }

    if (self.center.x < halfOfSuperviewWidth) {
        // Person is on the left of the screen and should not move to right side
        if ((location.x + halfOfPersonWidth) > halfOfSuperviewWidth) {
             return;
        }
    } else{
        // Person is on the right of the screen and should not move to left side
        if ((location.x - halfOfPersonWidth) < halfOfSuperviewWidth) {
            return;
        }
    }
    // If we have made it this far then we can move the Person
    // move to touch location on x axis only
    [self setCenter:CGPointMake(location.x, self.center.y)];
    }
```

Now in your View Controller class you can delete the original -touchesBegan & -touchesMoved code that you pasted here, Or just comment it out if you want to be cautious

```
 /* put slash asterisks above the code and asterisks slash below the code to comment out */
```

If you build and run you should be able to move each Person view around as before but if you put a finger on each Person view at the same time you should be able to move them simultaneously.

Comment: I'm a early beginner, sorry if i sound very in-experienced but do you mind showing me an example of how that would look code-wise? thank you very much for your input

Comment: No problem at all, give me 5 minutes

Comment: If that worked for you can you accept my answer - I need to increase my rep so I can comment.

Comment: @KristianFox I was also thinking about recommending moving the touch handling to Person class, but then he would have to move the x position limit (one person is controlled on one side of the screen, the other one on the other side) to this class, which can make stuff little bit more complicated (another properties & methods would be required in that class).

Comment: @KristianFox also, I'm not sure if your code will work, cause by `[touch locationInView:touch.view]` you're getting a location of the touch in Person's coordinate system. The center property is in superview's coordinate system, so you should rather do: `[touch locationInView:touch.view.superview];` or use `covertPoint:toView:` method afterwards.

Comment: thank you for all your help but unfortunately the code does not work as i do not have a person.m file. My mistake for not mentioning this early but the person and person 1 are IBOutlet images. I appreciate all your input

Comment: You say images, do you mean UIImageView rather than UIImage? You could create a Person class by subclassing UIImageView and then replace the UIImageView objects in you code with Person object.